# cannot login to Win10 as administrator, system disk inaccessible

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

A user accidentally removed all permissions from their system drive which is now inaccessible, as are programs in the menu or the RUN window, although Windows 10 still runs, and what's on the desktop can be launched. Can't run cmd as administrator (cmd.exe can't be accesses) but as current user I can.

I tried enabling administrator from the reboot command prompt and from registry,  but no way I can get option to choose login as administrator, won't show up. Whatever I change in the Registry is not saved.

Also tried resetting permissions with icocls but didn't help. After login, drive C: has no label and is inaccessible.

What else could be done to regain control of this OS?

Comment: 1. Restore from last image (presumably frequent in a manged environment) or 2. Reinstall Windows, keeping files.

Comment: got to be an option to prompt for enter login not just choose from list...reinstalling not posible for now.

Comment: when i reboot to command prompt it states administrator;  X:\windows  yet changes to  registry are not  preserved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use small little tool resetpermission from lallouslab to recover folder permissions.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Super User! Thanks for taking the time to answer this question. Unfortunately, the steps in this answer perhaps aren't quite as clear as they could be. Please consider expanding your instructions and adding any relevant details you believe are helpful.